# string method replace is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `replace` method of string,

```
     var text = this ex is not working.;
     text = text.replace(" ", "+");
     alert(text);
```

and got alert :

```
     this+ex is not working.
```

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all spaces with plus `+` character use the following:

```
var text = "this ex is not working.";
text = text.replace(/ /g, "+");
alert(text);
```

And don't forget to use quotes `"` for initializing strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **lil diff demo** http://jsfiddle.net/bLaZu/6/

**Please note:**

> The g flag on the RegExp, it will make the replacement globally within
>   the  string.

If you keen: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Rest feel free to play around with demo, `:)`

**code**

```
var text = "this ex is not working.";
     text = text.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
     alert(text);​
```

Comment: This answer is little more informative for novice than previous one. Voting for this answer.

Comment: @NikolayZakharov Glad you liked it, Have fun, see you around `:)`